# Using RegEx to split strings after specific character

Tags: c#, regex

I've been working on trying to get this string split in a couple different places which I managed to get to work, except if the name had a forward-slash in it, it would throw all of the groups off completely.

The string:

```
123.45.678.90:00000/98765432109876541/[CLAN]PlayerName joined [windows/12345678901234567]
```

I essentially need the following:

- IP group: 123.45.678.90:00000 (without the following /)
- id group: 98765432109876541
- name group: [CLAN]PlayerName
- id1 group: 12345678901234567

The text "joined" also has to be there. However windows does not.

Here is what I have so far:

```
(?<ip>.*)\/(?<id>.*)\/(.*\/)?(?<name1>.*)( joined.*)\[(.*\/)?(?<id1>.*)\]
```

This works like a charm *unless* the player name contains a "/". How would I go about escaping that?

Any help with this would be much appreciated!

Comment: Easiest solution: don't allow a `/` in player names. Or, translate a `/` in player name to something like `%SLASH%` and then display it as a `/` accordingly.

Comment: In the future, please post questions with a helpful title, "More than likely an easier way to do this. Probably a very simple fix" tells us nothing about the question.

Comment: @dubstylee you're assuming he has control over that. My guess, given the example, he's scraping from somewhere and therefore has no control over whether or not slashes are allowed.

Comment: Try `@"^(?<ip>[\d.:]*)/(?<id>\d+)/(?<name1>\S+) joined \[\w+/(?<id1>\d+)]$"` pattern. See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e(%3f%3cip%3e%5b%5cd.%3a%5d*)%2f(%3f%3cid%3e%5cd%2b)%2f(%3f%3cname1%3e%5cS%2b)+joined+%5c%5b%5cw%2b%2f(%3f%3cid1%3e%5cd%2b)%5d%5cr%3f%24&i=123.45.678.90%3a00000%2f98765432109876541%2f%5bCLAN%5dPlayerName+joined+%5bwindows%2f12345678901234567%5d%0d%0a76.6.161.255%3a50932%2f76561198211271144%2f%5bMERC%5dScRanDe+joined+%5bwindows%2f76561198211271144%5d&o=m).

Comment: Using '.*' create issues because it goes to end of string.  Terminate all groups with a not like following : string pattern = @"(?<ip>[^/]*)/(?<id>[^/]*)/(?<name1>[^\s]*)\s*(?<op>[^\s]*)[^/]*/(?<id1>[^\]]*)";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be using greedy quanitifiers (`*`) with an open character such as `.`. It won't work as intended and will result in a lot of backtracking.

This is slightly more efficient, but not overly strict:

```
^(?<ip>[^\/\n]+)\/(?<id>[^\/]+)\/(?<name1>\S+)\D+(?<id1>\d+)]$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nE7oL2/2)

Answer (score 1):

Since you tag your question with `C#` and `Regex` and not only `Regex`, I will propose an alternative. I am not sure if it will more efficient or not. I find it easiest to read and to debug if you simply use `String.Split()`:

[Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0fZhIG)

```
public void Main()
{
    string input = "123.45.678.90:00000/98765432109876541/[CLAN]Player/Na/me joined [windows/12345678901234567]";

    // we want "123.45.678.90:00000/98765432109876541/[CLAN]Player/Na/me joined" and "12345678901234567]"
    // Also, you can remove " joined" by adding it before " [windows/"
    var content = input.Split(new string[]{" [windows/"}, StringSplitOptions.None);

    // we want ip + groupId + everything else
    var tab = content[0].Split('/');

    var ip = tab[0];
    var groupId = tab[1];
    var groupName = String.Join("/", tab.Skip(2)); // merge everything else. We use Linq to skip ip and groupId
    var groupId1 = RemoveLast(content[1]); // cut the trailing ']'

    Console.WriteLine(groupName);
}

private static string RemoveLast(string s)
{
    return s.Remove(s.Length - 1);
}
```

Output:

```
[CLAN]Player/Na/me joined
```

If you are using a class for ip, groupId, etc. and I guess you do, just put everything in it with a constructor which accept a string as parameter.

Comment: I always lean towards String.Split over a regex for speed reasons, but I don't think your code solves the "what if a player name contains a slash" problem.

Answer (score 0):

You basically needs to use non greedy selectors (`*?`). Try this:

```
(?<ip>.*?)\/(?<id>.*?)\/(?<name1>.*?)( joined )\[(.*?\/)?(?<id1>.*?)\]
```

Comment: This worked like a charm. Always something so simple. I will accept once timer is up.

Comment: In C# regex patterns, you do not need to escape the `/` symbol. Do not use regex101 as a final check .NET regex tool as it does not support .NET regex syntax.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, I kept OP pattern on the regex101 example

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew They are kept for the sake of using regex101. If they are not, regex101 will show no match.

Comment: @JJEdgarVI: I do not think you have to depend on `/` regex delimiters (not used in .NET) there - https://regex101.com/r/oB3tM7/2

Comment: Indeed. If you'd like to create an answer I'll accept it. This works most efficiently.